# Cleanup xml file - Invalid character in the given encoding

Tags: c#, .net, xml, magento, deserialization

I am integrating against Magento ecommerce using their "SOAP" api, and the API returns "XML" results. Problem is, this is not always well formed:

```
<product>
   <entity_id>18</entity_id>
   <price regular="2925  <span>Nok</span>"/>
   ...
```

In this specific case, the price regular attribute has both an invisible character 0xa0 (before the span tag), and < > within the attribute text.

I have no way to get proper well-formed XML from Magento it seems, so the alternative is to clean it up before I feed it to my `XmlSerializer` deserialization:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Responses.Product.product));
product = serializer.Deserialize(textReader) as Responses.Product.product;
```

The invisible character I can get rid of using a simple text replace, but I'm more unsure about the <> within the attribute text.

My question is, how to clean it up for be valid XML?

Comment: I am afraid that what you have is not XML. It's an arbitrary string. So you cannot use an XML serializer to work with it. I would recommend you tackling the problem at its root which in your case is the generation of this string. All other attempts including *cleaning* it with replaces and/or regexes will eventually lead you to the abyss and your code will crash someday.

Comment: I don't generate this string, its the result of the SOAP call against Magento. This is what I have to work with, I cannot fix the provider of the string unfortunately :(

Comment: No, this cannot be a valid SOAP call. SOAP means XML. What you have shown here is very far from something that is called XML. So unless you are doing this call manually with an HttpWebRequest and ignoring the errors you get as response of the SOAP protocol completely this cannot happen with a compliant SOAP client.

Comment: Ok, so Magento calls it SOAP and XML, no matter what it really is. Not my fault Magento is so crap :) Whatever they call it, this is what I got to work with.

Comment: Good luck with this endeavor.

Comment: You are right, I am not using a SOAP client- since, as you said, it would never work. I am using WebClient to fetch the data. Sorry for confusing the problem description with the terms used by Magento, when it was not proper SOAP / XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character 0x3c is the `<` character. For an invisible character you would rather be looking for something like the 0x09 TAB character.

To fix the broken markup you could look for that specific HTML tag in the content, using a regular expression to allow any currency within the tag:

```
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "<span>([A-Za-z]{3})</span>", "&lt;span&gt;$1&lt;/span&gt;");
```

This works as long as there isn't any `span` elements in the XML code itself, with a three character content. You could do similar replacements for other HTML tags, but try to keep the pattern as specific as possible, to avoid false positives.

Comment: I'm sorry, the invisible character was 0xa0, not 0x3c.

Comment: @sphair: Aha, that's the LF (line feed) character. It's used as line break in Linux and OS X.